# SetState callback not waiting for state to update

Tags: javascript, react-native

Acording to the [setState documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) the callback should fire after the new state has been set. However, my code

```
console.log(school);
this.setState({ lastSegment: school },console.log(this.state.lastSegment));
```

Prints:

```
Middle
Grammar
```

Since school="Middle" why is the setState callback printing "Grammar" (which is the previous value of this.state.lastSegment)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `callback` is  a function passed to another function as an argument and sometimes referred as `anonymous` function which means a function without a name, so you're executing the `console.log` in place, and returning the value as the second argument to `setState`. You want to pass in a function, not the result of `console.log`.

```
this.setState({ lastSegment: school }, () => { 
  console.log(this.state.lastSegment); 
});
```

or using **ES5** syntax:

```
this.setState({ lastSegment: school }, function() { 
  console.log(this.state.lastSegment); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this applies to many scenarios. If you have a function you want to call for example foo, don't do `foo()` do `foo`